# Where Is my wrong

Tags: probability

The random variables given for the PDF distribution function:

$$
p_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    \frac{a}{7}x, & 2 <x\leq 3   \\
    0, & x\notin(2,3] \\
\end{cases}
$$

$a)$ Find value of parametric $a$, and $F_X(x)$ (CDF).

$b)$ find the probability that the random variables is part of interval $(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2})\$

My attemp is: First part
$a)$ $$\int_2^3\frac{a}{7}xdx=1\Rightarrow a=\frac{14}{5}$$
Now we have:
$$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    \frac{14}{35}x, & 2 <x\leq 3   \\
    0, & x\notin(2,3] \\
\end{cases}
$$

Case 1: If $x<2$ we have $F_X(x)=0$

Case 2: If $2<x\leq 3$ we have: $F_X(x)=\int_2^x\frac{14}{35}udu\Rightarrow F_X(x)=\frac{7}{35}x^2-\frac{28}{35}$

Case 3: If $x>3$ we have $F_X(x)=1$

Now for the second part

$b)$ If $x<2$ for the function $F_X(x)$ we have $F_X(x)=0$ so the values ​​of the interval remain $(\2,\frac{5}{2})\$. From here

$$P(X\in(2,\frac{5}{2}))=F(\frac{5}{2})-F(2)=\frac{7}{35}\frac{25}{4}-\frac{28}{35}-\frac{7}{35}4-\frac{28}{35}=-\frac{161}{120}????$$

i don't know where i went wrong. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Your notation seems wrong. $F_X$ is the CDF not the PDF.

Comment: I correct, sorry

Comment: why the replacement should be done only once

Answer (score -1):

You're wrong at the last line by substracting $\frac{28}{35}$ twice, since you forgot to flip the sign the second time.

$$F_X(\frac{5}{2}) - F_X(2) = \frac{1}{5}\frac{25}{4} - \frac{4}{5} - \big(\frac{1}{5}4 - \frac{4}{5}\big) = \frac{1}{5}\big(\frac{25}{4} - 4\big)$$

Comment: Just pay attention at the $-$ sign before the parentheses, it flips the sign in the parentheses...

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: I am not a negative vote

Comment: why the replacement should be done only once

Comment: What do you mean by the replacement should be done only once ?

Comment: $P(x\in(2,\frac{5}{2}))=F(\frac{5}{2})-F(2)=\frac{7}{35}\cdot\frac{25}{4}-\frac{7}{35}\cdot\ 4-\frac{28}{35}=-49/120$

Comment: Your last $-$ sign should be $+$

Comment: why? in the function $F_X(x)=\frac{7}{35}x^2-\frac{28}{35}$

Comment: What's the value of $-F_X(x)$ More exactly the value of $-F_X(2)$ ?

Comment: So first of all, your multiplication is completely wrong. 35 * 4 is 140 not 120. Second of all if you simplify your fraction you get the answer I wrote you initially.